# running `git push` on AWS seems to fail

Tags: git, github, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've suddenly experienced odd behavior on an EC2 instance in AWS. Specifically, I can't `git push` but I can do other git commands. When I try to `git push` I get:

```
git push
ssh: connect to host github-fs109-cp1-prd.iad.github.net. port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Wait a minute, when I try to resolve that hostname it gives me a private IP: 172.16.128.17

So obviously github is hosted on AWS but it's not accepting any connections from the private network IP within AWS. So what about trying to debug the SSH connection? It works!

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/w/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.129] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/w/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/w/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/w/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1+github5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1+github5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/w/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
Hi ___________! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2272, received 2920 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 46661.6, received 59970.0
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Is this a known issue? What's the solution here?

Also, I played around with `.ssh/config` file to try to specify hosts there, or public IPs to github.com, still the same result.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: What does `git remote -v` show?

Comment: This: origin git@github.com:repo/repo.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:repo/repo.git (push)

Now after I ran than and then `git push`, it worked. Huh?

Comment: sounds like it was just a hiccup in service or something, not sure.  Glad it's working now though!

Comment: Try "GIT_TRACE=1 git push " to see some trace messages. It might give useful info.